# Sub DataFrame extraction error (list index out of range)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, slice

I am running error saying: IndexError: list index out of range

when running this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as wb
import datetime as dt

data = wb.DataReader('spy', 'yahoo', start='1/1/1978', end='30/10/2019')
data['Change'] = data['Close'].pct_change() * 100
data['Gaps'] = (((data['Open'] - data['Close'].shift(1))/data['Close'].shift(1)) * 100)
data['Gaps'].astype(float)
data['Performance during day'] = ((data['Close'] - data['Open'])/data['Open']) * 100
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data['Date'] = data['Date'].dt.date
data = round(data, 2)

filtered_data = list((data[data['Gaps'] > 2].index.astype(int)))


list_of_slices = []

for each in filtered_data:
    event = data.iloc[filtered_data[each]-30:filtered_data[each]+60]
    list_of_slices.append(event)
```

I want to extract part of the Dataframe and create new Sub dataframe from data extracted to plot afterwards candlestick chart

Comment: change `event = data.iloc[filtered_data[each]-30:filtered_data[each]+60]` to `event = data.iloc[each-30:each+60]`

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice. Worked perfectly